# When trying to create or connect to a database with phpMyAdmin browser shows a blank page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My phpMyAdmin is running correctly but when I create or connect to a database through my XAMPP server local host shows blank page on browser.  I am confused about it because it is not showing any error but showing just a blank page.

Comment: can you provide error log provided by apache or php?

Comment: the apche or php is showing no error or any warning.when i type the code then there is no error also.

Comment: i have created a database though phpmyadmin and a database through code but when i try to connect to database just like when we write   
$con =mysql_connect("localhost","root","password",db);
if(!$con){
 die("can not connect:" . mysql_error());
}
echo "Welcome";

Then no error displayed n browser shows blank screen

Comment: not on website. There are logs produced by one of them -- maybe you will have to learn how to enable them before.

Comment: how to enable them???

Comment: in xampp control panel  there is a log option are you mentioning that

Comment: I am not familiar with XAMPP, but it will be probably the one. Please, investigate little before asking another question.

Comment: i have searched about the log enabling. and set the values the recommended for the file php.ini. but still blank screen